# Autofit Column Width using SSIS ETL on Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, column-width

I´m creating an ETL on visual studio, but when I export my data to a table on Excel, the columns seem a bit short. Is there a way to autofit the column width from visual studio? Thank you

**Update 1**

Here is the code as I copied it and also the error I get

[image: Code]

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can achieve this using a `script task` that execute after the `DataFlow Task` success. You have to add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly to the script task references and use the following code:** *(used Vb.Net)*

*Note: you have to add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll file to the following directories (.Net Framework dll directory)  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and (sql server data tools dll directory) C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn (using vs 2005 and sql 2008) and then add this dll as a reference in your script task*

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Sub Main()

    Dim strFile as String = "C:\New Folder\1.xls"
    Dim m_XlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim m_xlWrkbs As Excel.Workbooks = m_XlApp.Workbooks
    Dim m_xlWrkb As Excel.Workbook

    m_xlWrkb = m_xlWrkbs.Open(strFile)

    'Loop over all worksheets
    For Each m_XlWrkSheet As Excel.Worksheet In m_xlWrkb.Worksheets

        'Columns    
        m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit()

        'Rows
        m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit()


    Next

    m_xlWrkb.Save()
    m_xlWrkb.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    m_XlApp.Quit()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But I´m still having problems. I did everything you sayd and I get some errors. I´ll post an answer with the errors

Comment: First you have to replace `c:\new folder\..` with your excel path

Comment: Second try to run package in 32-bit mode  http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/faq%20-%20how%20to%20run%20ssis%20packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm

Comment: Also The exception is thrown because some of the libraries referenced from a missing folder.
Removing the references and adding them back from the correct path fixed the issue.