# How to auto fit columns (width) using Excel Destination in SSIS?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I am working on an SSIS-2012 project, where I am receiving dataset after executing a stored procedure and saving the data in an excel file using an "Excel Destination" task in data flow. It works well, however I have a problem that for some fields, the width of columns are not large enough to show the value. Some numbers are shown like ##### for example, or part of a sentence instead of whole the end user sees etc.

Usually I handle this problem in Visual studio using a code like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= RAWDATA_COLUMNS.Length; i++)
{
    worksheet.Column(i).AutoFit();
}
```

However, here I could not find a way to handle it in SSIS. Writing a script to receive the data and save it into Excel file is not an option, using Excel Destination task in data flow is a must. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The `######` is just what Excel displays with the column is too narrow. The data is still there. All you have to do is open the file and then adjust the column(s) until the correct data appears. Or is there a reason your users can't adjust the column widths after they open the file?

Comment: Users don't want to adjust it themselves, want the file adjusted already.

Comment: This is a potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504806/autofit-column-width-using-ssis-etl-on-visual-studio